# How to install Octave Package from Windows command line?

Tags: command-line, package, installation, octave

I am trying to install an Octave package from the command line, but I need to do it without having to launch the CLI and then run code to install the package. Ideally I want to have a gulp task that will copy the file from a network location and then install the package. I've got the copy part working fine but all attempts to install the package from the command line have failed.

I've created a basic .m file containing the following

```
function installPackage()
  pkg ("install", "rod-marker-analysis.tar.gz");
end
```

I've tried adding `pkg load io` to the above code that had not change on the output.

I've tried running this file from the command line (as admin and not) using the Octave CLI

```
"C:\Octave\Octave-5.1.0.0\mingw64\bin\octave-5.1.0.bat" --no-history installPackage.m
```

I have tried the above calling `octave-cli.exe`, `octave.bat`, `octave`, and `octave-5.1.0.bat`. All result in the following error. I've tried adjusting file permissions and still run into the same issue.

> unpack: unarchiving program exited with status: 1
>   tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/d/dev/OctaveInstaller/rod-marker-analysis.tar.gz'
>   error: called from
>       unpack at line 274 column 5
>       untar at line 48 column 5
>       install at line 81 column 9
>       pkg at line 441 column 9
>       installPackage at line 8 column 3

I also tried creating a command line tool using the Octave.NET nuget package and I get the following exception.

> unpack: unarchiving program exited with status: 1
>   tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/C/dev/Gammex/rapidcheck/Utilities/Gammex.Tools.Octave/Gammex.Tools.OctaveCommandRunner/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/rod-marker-analysis.tar.gz'
>   error: called from
>       unpack at line 274 column 5
>       untar at line 48 column 5
>       install at line 81 column 9
>       pkg at line 441 column 9
>       installPackage at line 5 column 3

Comment: Are you sure your .tar.gz is valid? Does it install from the Octave interpreter?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to install it if I use pkg install inside the Octave CLI or GUI.